# Amazon SES with a subdomain

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, subdomain, amazon-ses

I have a domain, `lab.example.com`. And I've been playing around with SES. What I want to do is use SES with `lab.example.com`.

I've run the following commands:

```
dig cname random-string-of-characters-1._domainkey.lab.example.com
dig -t txt _amazonses.lab.example.com
```

I would expect to see a question (usually my cname or txt record) and the answer (the aws cname and the txt answer). Something like this:

```
cname: Question -> random-string-of-characters-1._comainkey.lab.example.com
cname: Answer -> random-string-of-characters-1.dkim.amazonses.com
txt: Question -> _amazonses.lab.example.com
txt: Answer -> "dkim text information"
```

However I that is not what i'm receiving. What I'm getting is this: https://pastebin.com/Bkx3TXMK

What I had hoped to see is this: https://pastebin.com/jV3UQWgw

If someone can provide some advice I would appreciate it?

Comment: Please put all relevant commands and replies in the question itself, and not in a remote pastebin. Also generic recommendation when using `dig`: always specify the nameserver you query using `@`, starting with authoritative ones, then recursive ones (depending on what you are trying to troubleshoot).

Comment: You got a `NXDOMAIN` reply: it means the record does not exist at all, and since the authority is at `example.com` it is probably because `lab.example.com` does not exist at all at the nameserver you are querying.

Comment: FWIW in your obfuscation, in the second link your forgot to change the `tech` in `example.tech` for a `com`. This makes the dig question and reply completely unrelated, but then anyone understands the case nevertheless. It just shows the perils of obfuscation...